# How many assists did Maradona give in World Cups?

Tags: football, statistics, world-cup

There are several websites stating this top for World Cup assists

> 1- Pele (10)
>
> 2- Messi (6)
>
> 3- James Rodriguez (5)
>
> 4- Juan Cuadrado (5)
>
> 5- Thomas Muller (4)

[Most assists in World cup](https://www.worldcupglory.com/records/most-assists-in-fifa-world-cup/)

[Top 5 players most assists in World Cup](https://khelnow.com/football/top-five-players-most-assists-fifa-world-cup)

But they have to be wrong, because Maradona is said to give 8 assists in World Cups, and I know from other sources that in 1986 alone he gave 5 assists (and 5 goals)

[Maradona: His World Cup stats which may never be matched](https://www.besoccer.com/new/maradona-dies-his-world-cup-stats-which-may-never-be-matched-920741#:%7E:text=As%20well%20as%20eight%20goals,player%20has%20accumulated%20as%20many.)

So, how many assists did Maradona give in World Cups?

Comment: I find it hard to believe that only four players in World Cup history have achieved five assists, especially considering the number of players that have reached five goals. Maradona can't be the only omission from those lists.

Comment: I suspect some of that is because assists have been an even semi-official stat only in the past 20(?) or so years.